# Dxf : how to know which layers to show?

Tags: .net, layer, dxf, dxflib

I have to parse dxf files to transform it to images in .net.

I used DxfLib (https://github.com/mkernel/DXFLib).

I have a probleme with layers : I have 3 layers and only one need to be shown (I uploaded my file in some dxf viewer and they only show one layer)

I don't know how to know if a layer need to be shown or not. I didn't find the information in my dxf parsed file.

Do you know where i can find this ? (maybe it's a missing element from DxfLib)

EDIT : there is a exemple of my dxf file : https://github.com/mkernel/DXFLib/files/286112/DIAMOND-R.zip

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **DXF** file contains a **LAYERS** *table* in the **HEADER** section. Here is the details about the layer table **record**:

http://www.autodesk.com/techpubs/autocad/acad2000/dxf/layer_dxf_04.htm

You are interested in group code **62**:

[image: Group code 62]

As you can see, if the layer colour is **negative** the layer is switched **off**. Here is an example:

```
  0
LAYER
  5
242
330
2
100
AcDbSymbolTableRecord
100
AcDbLayerTableRecord
  2
LAYER2
 70
     0
 62
    -3
  6
Continuous
370
    -3
390
F
347
EE
348
0
  0
ENDTAB
```

So, when you process an entity and examine the layer value, lookup it up in the **LAYERS** table in the **HEADER** section. This is the start of that section:

```
  0
TABLE
  2
LAYER
```

Once located, examine the **colour** property and if **negative**, the layer is switched off.

I do not know what features **DXFLib** has available for parsing the HEADERS section of the DXF file. But I hope this detail helps you!

Comment: Thank you for your answer but in my case the color is 7 for every layers :(

Comment: Can you share your complete DXF file? Perhaps you only have the ENTITIES section.

Comment: Thanks for sending. You have 5 objects in your drawing and they are all defined on layer "0".

Comment: I maybe found something : i use DrawingExtendsLowerRight and DrawingExtendsUpperRight to not show what is ouside theses values

Comment: Ok. If you can do a more complete dxf I can check again.

Comment: i send it by email (to your company email address)

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found a solution !

My problem was not to show/hide a layer but how to detect and hide unrelevant objects.

I use `DrawingExtendsLowerRight` and `DrawingExtendsUpperRight` properties in header section to know the limits of my drawing. I only keep elements that are in the limits.